# How to make a stack in LaTeX?

Tags: stack

I want to make a stack (as in programming but not algebraic one...) in LaTeX. For example, I want to define a set {} with the last three operation:

1. Add a number at the last of the set.
2. Take the last number of the set.
3. Delete the last number of the set.

How do I make this true in LaTeX?

Comment: see interface3.pdf: "The l3seq package Sequences and stacks"

Answer (score 7):

An implementation based on `interface3`, “Sequences and stacks”

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_ngiap_stack_seq
\msg_new:nnnn { ngiap } { stackempty }
 {
  Take~or~delete~from~empty~stack
 }
 {
  You've~attempted~to~take~or~delete~from~an~empty~stack
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\stackpush}{m}
 {
  \seq_push:Nn \l_ngiap_stack_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\stackget}{o}
 {
  \seq_get:NNTF \l_ngiap_stack_seq \l_tmpa_tl
   {
    \IfValueTF { #1 }
     {
      \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
     }
     {
      \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
     }
   }
   {
    \msg_error:nn { ngiap } { stackempty }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\stackpop}{o}
 {
  \seq_pop:NN \l_ngiap_stack_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \quark_if_no_value:NTF \l_tmpa_tl
   {
    \msg_error:nn { ngiap } { stackempty }
   }
   {
    \IfValueTF { #1 }
     {
      \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
     }
     {
      \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
     }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\stackshow}{}{\seq_show:N \l_ngiap_stack_seq}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\stackshow

\stackpush{1}\stackshow

\stackget\stackshow

\stackpush{2}\stackshow

\stackget\stackshow
\stackget[\foo]\show\foo

\stackpop[\baz]\show\baz\stackshow
\stackpop\stackshow
\stackpop\stackshow

\end{document}
```

With `\stackpush` we add an item at the top of the stack. With `\stacktake` we access the top item, optionally saving it in a macro; this doesn't change the stack. With `\stackpop` we access the top item, optionally saving it in a macro, deleting it from the stack.

The example file will print

1
2
1

and show the following output in the console:

```
The sequence \l_ngiap_stack_seq is empty
> .
<recently read> }

l.59 \stackshow

?
The sequence \l_ngiap_stack_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {1}.
<recently read> }

l.61 \stackpush{1}\stackshow

?
The sequence \l_ngiap_stack_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {1}.
<recently read> }

l.63 \stackget\stackshow

?
The sequence \l_ngiap_stack_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {2}
>  {1}.
<recently read> }

l.65 \stackpush{2}\stackshow

?
The sequence \l_ngiap_stack_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {2}
>  {1}.
<recently read> }

l.67 \stackget\stackshow

?
> \foo=macro:
->2.
l.68 \stackget[\foo]\show\foo

?
> \baz=macro:
->2.
l.70 \stackpop[\baz]\show\baz
                             \stackshow
?
The sequence \l_ngiap_stack_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {1}.
<recently read> }

l.70 \stackpop[\baz]\show\baz\stackshow

?
The sequence \l_ngiap_stack_seq is empty
> .
<recently read> }

l.71 \stackpop\stackshow

?

! Package ngiap Error: Take or delete from empty stack

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.72 \stackpop\stackshow

?
The sequence \l_ngiap_stack_seq is empty
> .
<recently read> }

l.72 \stackpop\stackshow

?
```

Comment: What, it's about programming? I was hoping that "make a stack" referred to a stack of money.